# IE : Left Navigation for positon sticky not working

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

There is a left navigation on our site which has a `positon:sticky`. This does not work in IE browser. We have tried to change it to `position:fixed` by giving `top:XXpx;` .  We have a specific requirement where the left navigation becomes visible only after certain scroll and then it becomes sticky. I have tried to get its scrollTop by using jQuery . But surprisingly it always give me zero. 
You can check the link 
https://gac.icann.org/working-group/gac-public-safety-working-group-pswg. 
Any piece of code will be largely appreciated.

Comment: You should check the answer URL of related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646066/css-sticky-buttons-div-not-working-in-ie-11

Comment: Thanks but I have already mentioned this.In a nutshell, what I want is when should I make the position from relative to fixed for the left nav..