# jQuery Plugin does not work with Angular 5 (plugin is not a function)

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, types

I try to get a jQuery plugin (stickyNavbar) work with Angular 5. But I always get the error `$(...).stickyNavbar is not a function` (Image below)

**.angular-cli.json**

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "../src/assets/js/jquery.stickyNavbar.min.js"
],
```

**Component**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';


ngOnInit() {

    $(function () {
      alert('Hello'); // This works
      $('.menu-card').stickyNavbar(); // stickyNavbar is not a functin
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.loading = false;
    }, 1000)
  }
```

**Error**

[image]

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934727/how-to-use-jquery-plugin-with-angular-4)

Comment: does `$('.menu-card').stickyNavbar()` work if you type it in the developer console?

Comment: Yes - it works when I write it in the developer console..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add scripts to the `angular.json` file, the bundler already adds them. You don't need to use `import`. If you do, your scripts will be additional bundled as modules. For your scenario, you just need to declare the $ variable as any:

```
declare var $: any;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the script can't recognize jQuery, giving the error

> "jQuery is not defined" or
>   "$(...).myCurrentPlugin is not a function"

To get the plugin to work you have to do the following:

go to the plugin file inside node modules, wrap it in the following way:

old version:

```
jQuery.fn.myPlugin= function (y) {y ...
```

new version:

```
export default function test(jQuery) {
    jQuery.fn.myPlugin= function (y) {y ... (all plugin code)
    }
```

then in the angular component:

```
import myPlugin from "node_modules/myPuglin/myPuglin.min.js"
import * as jquery from 'jquery';
let $: any = jquery;
myPlugin($)
```

now it works

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem.

Try doing this :

```
npm install jquery
```

then, import jquery in your required page as :

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Comment: No need to inject it in **.json** . Just install jquery by using `npm install jquery --save` then try it. same you can do it with bootstrap and popper @eleinad

Answer (score 0):

JQuery doesn't work well with Angular in many cases so its a better approach to find a plugin compatible with Angular. or simply achieve this using css.
[sticky-angular-material-header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52634838/angular-6-css-sticky-header)

you can also use package `angular-material` or `ngx-bootstrap` which provides this functionality right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for solution.
I had the similar issue with another plugin. None of the solution did work for me. I had to remove `import * as $ from "jquery"` from the ts file.

Reason:
If you have installed the jquery from cli using the command below then there is no need to import jquery in every ts file. Jquery will be available across all ts files.

```sh
npm install jquery --save,
npm install @types/jquery --save
```

If you import the jquery in ts file, only the functions that come with `jquery.min.js` will be available. So, if you have referenced any external jquery plugins, those functions will not be available. You can make it compile by including in typing.d.s but it will fail in runtime.

My complete solution:

1. Install jquery from cli
2. Import the external jquery plugin files in `index.html`
3. Configure typing for external plugin in the `typings.d.ts` file.
4. Use $/jquery and plugin in any .ts file.