# Make element sticky in IE11

Tags: html, css

I have a menu which is positioned absolutely on a right of a page.
The menu's header must be fixed when the menu is scrolled.
I used position:sticky but it doesn't work in IE11.

```css
.panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.panel-header-wrapper {
  background: blue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-header-wrapper">
    Sticky header
  </div>
  <div class="panel-inner">
    <ul>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
      <li>123</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've checked the answers in a similar ticket, position:fixed wouldn't work for me, neither do I can use extra libs:
[CSS Sticky buttons div not working in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646066/css-sticky-buttons-div-not-working-in-ie-11)

Any ideas ?

Comment: You need script to support IE11

Answer (score 2):

`position: sticky;` isn't supported in IE 11 or earlier, it was only added in Edge. You'll either have to use `position: fixed;` or use this polyfill: https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/stickybits
I got this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46830918/8602926