# How to create position sticky like effect in IE with both side scroll able table?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-table

I have created table which has sticky header (scrollable)in both horizontally and vertically. Everything working fine in Chrome and Firefox, bit sticky header not working in IE as IE does not support position:sticky, I am trying with position: fixed but problem in this is table is not scrolling vertically as required.

I am trying to achieve this only using HTML CSS

Please suggest any trick,

```css
.draggable-table {
  display: flex;
  height: 35rem;
  border: 0.1rem solid #f2f2f2;
  overflow: auto;
}

.draggable-table__column {
  width: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 0.1rem solid #f2f2f2;
  height: -moz-fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  /* to make column sticky */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 40.625em) {
  .draggable-table__column {
    min-width: 10rem;
  }
}

.draggable-table__column .pin-cell {
  width: 7rem;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: width .5s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* for checked pinned*/
}

.draggable-table__column .pin-cell .checker {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 40.625em) {
  .draggable-table__column .pin-cell .checker {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.draggable-table__column .pin-cell input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .checker {
  opacity: 1;
}

.draggable-table__column:hover .pin-cell {
  width: 10rem;
  transition: width .5s;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 40.625em) {
  .draggable-table__column:hover .pin-cell {
    width: auto;
  }
}

.draggable-table__column:hover .pin-cell .checker {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .2s linear;
}

.draggable-table__column:first-child {
  order: -6;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0.1rem 0.3rem 0.8rem 0 rgba(30, 37, 74, 0.09), 0.1rem 0.1rem 0.3rem 0 rgba(30, 37, 74, 0.18);
  min-width: 9rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 40.625em) {
  .draggable-table__column:first-child {
    width: 15rem;
  }
}

.draggable-table__column:first-child .pin-cell {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.draggable-table__column:first-child .column-header {
  width: auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 40.625em) {
  .draggable-table__column:first-child .column-header {
    min-width: 2rem;
  }
}

.draggable-table__column > .row-header, .draggable-table__column > .column-cell {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1.6rem;
  height: 12rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.draggable-table__column > .row-header:nth-child(even), .draggable-table__column > .column-cell:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.draggable-table__column.pinned {
  order: -1;
  position: sticky;
  left: 15rem;
  z-index: 3;
}

.draggable-table__column.pinned .pin-cell {
  visibility: visible;
}

.draggable-table input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 4rem;
  opacity: 0;
}

.draggable-table input[type="checkbox"] + .checker {
  background: url("../graphics/sim-card-migration_retain-number.png");
  background-size: auto 100%;
  width: 4rem;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 1.6rem 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.draggable-table input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.draggable-table input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .checker {
  background: url("../graphics/sim-card-migration_new-number.png");
  background-size: auto 100%;
  width: 4rem;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 1.6rem 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.draggable-table .column-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: .4rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0.9rem 0.8rem 0 rgba(30, 37, 74, 0.09), 0 0.1rem 0 0 rgba(30, 37, 74, 0.18);
  width: auto;
  height: 8rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 40.625em) {
  .draggable-table .column-header {
    min-width: 10rem;
  }
}

.draggable-table .checkbox {
  padding: .3rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.draggable-table .pin-cell {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1.6rem 0;
  position: relative;
}

.draggable-table .row-header-text {
  color: #575756;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.draggable-table .row-header-subtext {
  color: #8c8d8e;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.6rem;
}

.draggable-table .cell-text {
  color: #575756;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.draggable-table .cell-subtext {
  color: #8c8d8e;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.6rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="draggable-table">

        <!-- 1st sticky column -->
        <div class="draggable-table__column">
            <div class="pin-cell"><input type="checkbox"><label class="checker"></label></div>
            <div class="column-header"></div>

            <div class="row-header">
                <div class="row-header-text">Test Data</div>
                <div class="row-header-subtext">Test Subtext</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-header">
                <div class="row-header-text">Test Data</div>
                <div class="row-header-subtext">Test Subtext</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-header">
                <div class="row-header-text">Test Data</div>
                <div class="row-header-subtext">Test Subtext</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-header">
                <div class="row-header-text">Test Data</div>
                <div class="row-header-subtext">Test Subtext</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-header">
                <div class="row-header-text">Test Data</div>
                <div class="row-header-subtext">Test Subtext</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-header">
                <div class="row-header-text">Test Data</div>
                <div class="row-header-subtext">Test Subtext</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-header">
                <div class="row-header-text">Test Data</div>
                <div class="row-header-subtext">Test Subtext</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-header">
                <div class="row-header-text">Test Data</div>
                <div class="row-header-subtext">Test Subtext</div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- column -->
        <div class="draggable-table__column">
            <div class="pin-cell"> <input id="trigger" type="checkbox"> <label class="checker"></div>
            <div class="column-header"><div class="row-header-text"> Data</div> <div class="row-header-subtext">€123 p/m</div></div>

            <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> <div class="row-header-subtext">include</div> </div>

                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>

          </div>
        <div class="draggable-table__column">
            <div class="pin-cell"> <input id="trigger" type="checkbox"> <label class="checker"></div>
            <div class="column-header"><div class="row-header-text"> Data</div> <div class="row-header-subtext">€123 p/m</div></div>

            <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> <div class="row-header-subtext"></div> </div>

                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>

          </div>
        <div class="draggable-table__column">
            <div class="pin-cell"> <input id="trigger" type="checkbox"> <label class="checker"></div>
            <div class="column-header"><div class="row-header-text"> Data</div> <div class="row-header-subtext">€123 p/m</div></div>

            <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> <div class="row-header-subtext"></div> </div>

                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>

          </div>
        <div class="draggable-table__column">
            <div class="pin-cell"> <input id="trigger" type="checkbox"> <label class="checker"></div>
            <div class="column-header"><div class="row-header-text"> Data</div> <div class="row-header-subtext">€123 p/m</div></div>

            <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> <div class="row-header-subtext"></div> </div>

                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>

          </div>
        <div class="draggable-table__column">
            <div class="pin-cell"> <input id="trigger" type="checkbox"> <label class="checker"></div>
            <div class="column-header"><div class="row-header-text"> Data</div> <div class="row-header-subtext">€123 p/m</div></div>

            <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> <div class="row-header-subtext"></div> </div>

                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>

          </div>
        <div class="draggable-table__column">
            <div class="pin-cell"> <input id="trigger" type="checkbox"> <label class="checker"></div>
            <div class="column-header"><div class="row-header-text"> Data</div> <div class="row-header-subtext">€123 p/m</div></div>

            <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> <div class="row-header-subtext"></div> </div>

                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>

          </div>
        <div class="draggable-table__column">
            <div class="pin-cell"> <input id="trigger" type="checkbox"> <label class="checker"></div>
            <div class="column-header"><div class="row-header-text"> Data</div> <div class="row-header-subtext">€123 p/m</div></div>

            <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> <div class="row-header-subtext"></div> </div>

                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>

          </div>
        <div class="draggable-table__column">
            <div class="pin-cell"> <input id="trigger" type="checkbox"> <label class="checker"></div>
            <div class="column-header"><div class="row-header-text"> Data</div> <div class="row-header-subtext">€123 p/m</div></div>

            <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> <div class="row-header-subtext"></div> </div>

                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>
                <div class="column-cell"> <div class="cell-text">€25</div> </div>

          </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Thank You

Comment: So this is NOT a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646066/position-sticky-buttons-not-working-in-ie-11 ?

Comment: @mplungjan I am trying to get solution only using HTML CSS

Answer (score 0):

Since it is scroll able, I think it is hard to achieve it only using HTML and CSS. When we scroll the content, we need to use JavaScript to move the header and first column, please refer to the following [sample](https://codepen.io/MaxArt2501/pen/qLCmE):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .fix-column {
            float: left;
        }

        .thead {
            height: 40px;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

            .thead > span {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 120px;
                line-height: 40px;
                box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
                background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.3);
                text-align: center;
            }

        .trow {
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

            .trow > span {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 120px;
                box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
                line-height: 80px;
                height: 80px;
            }

        .tbody {
            height: 300px;
            overflow: auto;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .fix-column > .tbody {
            overflow: hidden;
            /*padding-bottom: 50px;*/
        }
            /*.fix-column > .tbody > .trow:last-child {margin-bottom: 50px;}*/

            .fix-column > .tbody > .trow {
                margin-top: -50px;
                margin-bottom: 50px;
            }

                .fix-column > .tbody > .trow:first-child {
                    margin-top: 0px;
                }

        .rest-columns {
            width: 350px;
        }

            .rest-columns > .thead {
                /*padding-right: 50px;*/
                overflow: hidden;
            }
                /*.rest-columns > .thead > :last-child {margin-right: 50px;}*/
                .rest-columns > .thead > span {
                    margin-right: 50px;
                    margin-left: -50px;
                }

                .rest-columns > .thead > :first-child {
                    margin-left: 0px;
                }
    </style>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var fcBody = document.querySelector(".fix-column > .tbody"),
                rcBody = document.querySelector(".rest-columns > .tbody"),
                rcHead = document.querySelector(".rest-columns > .thead");
            rcBody.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
                fcBody.scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
                rcHead.scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
            }, { passive: true });
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="total-wrapper">
        <div class="fix-column">
            <div class="thead">
                <span>Int1</span>
            </div>
            <div class="tbody">
                <div class="trow">
                    <span>Lorem</span>
                </div>
                <div class="trow">
                    <span>Lorem</span>
                </div>
                <div class="trow">
                    <span>Lorem</span>
                </div>
                <div class="trow">
                    <span>Lorem</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rest-columns">
            <div class="thead">
                <span>Int2</span><span>Int3</span><span>Int4</span><span>Int5</span>
            </div>
            <div class="tbody">
                <div class="trow">
                    <span>ipsum</span><span>dolor</span><span>sit</span><span>amet</span>
                </div>
                <div class="trow">
                    <span>ipsum</span><span>dolor</span><span>sit</span><span>amet</span>
                </div>
                <div class="trow">
                    <span>ipsum</span><span>dolor</span><span>sit</span><span>amet</span>
                </div>
                <div class="trow">
                    <span>ipsum</span><span>dolor</span><span>sit</span><span>amet</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result like this:

[image]

Besides, you could also check [this sample](https://jsfiddle.net/RMarsh/bzuasLcz/3/).

Comment: Thanks for nice example. But I have achieved this using HTML CSS, but I am getting issue in IE. There are some reason that I can not use <tr> <td>. Is there any using my solution to achieve this in IE?

Comment: In the above example, it's also not use <tr> <td>, please check it. Not found a good method to achieve your requirement just using HTML and CSS, because the Internet Explorer doesn't support position: sticky.