# How can we use position :sticky; property in table to stick the header part?

Tags: html, css, web-applications, responsive-design

The structure of my code is

```
<div>
     <table>
        <thead>
        <th></th>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
 </div>
```

Header part of my code

```
<div class="box-body" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block; height: 636px; overflow: auto">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-fit table-fixed myBorderColor" style="width: 100%;">
       <thead>
           <th style="width: 15%; position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky; top :0;">
               <spring:message code="my_label_name" />
           </th>
           <c:forEach items="${listForHeader[0].getListWeek()}"
               var="dayOfWeek" varStatus="week">
               <th colspan="3" class="text-center" style="position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky; top: 0; ">
                   <c:if test="${dayOfWeek.week == 1}">
                       <spring:message code="my_label_monday" />
                       <br></br>
                       ${dayOfWeek.day}
                   </c:if> 
                   <c:if test="${dayOfWeek.week == 2}">
                       <spring:message code="my_label_tuesday" />
                       <br></br>
                       ${dayOfWeek.day}
                   </c:if> 
                   <c:if test="${dayOfWeek.week == 3}">
                       <spring:message code="my_label_wednesday" />
                       <br></br>
                           ${dayOfWeek.day}
                   </c:if>
                   <c:if test="${dayOfWeek.week == 4}">
                       <spring:message code="my_label_thursday" />
                       <br></br>
                       ${dayOfWeek.day}
                   </c:if> 
                   <c:if test="${dayOfWeek.week == 5}">
                       <spring:message code="my_label_friday" />
                       <br></br>
                       ${dayOfWeek.day}
                   </c:if>
                   <c:if test="${dayOfWeek.week == 6}">
                       <spring:message code="my_label_saturday" />
                       <br></br> 
                       ${dayOfWeek.day}
                   </c:if> 
                   <c:if test="${dayOfWeek.week == 7}">
                       <spring:message code="my_label_sunday" />
                       <br></br> 
                       ${dayOfWeek.day}
                   </c:if>
               </th>
           </c:forEach>
       </thead>
```

I want to fix this header as sticky so
I use `style="width: 15%; position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky; top :0;"` in  tag and 
`<div class="box-body" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block; height: 636px; overflow: auto">`
it works in chrome But it does not work in Internet Explorer, also I tried out position: fixed, 
but it also does not works in IE. Can you give some alternative to fix header.

Answer (score 0):

**position:sticky** is not supported in IE.
Have a look at the browser support at https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky

Maybe **position:fixed** is the solution as mentioned here : [Position: sticky buttons not working in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646066/position-sticky-buttons-not-working-in-ie-11#37646381)

Hope this would help.